# Resizing a div relying on the position of one of its vertex

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Context of the problem:** I am using a 960px grid and for now my layout looks like on [this little piece of art](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1esyQw6jz9FReHeh4ZjkuRLnE-YXcwYZ1CJ4OjKEBGHM/edit) :) 
But I want it actually to look more like [this](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1awzoL84k6IX37utxSrzrwDw9nflUYyB2qX48wqbzGM4/edit), where you can see that the sidebar is "visually" stuck to the left border of the window.

Now it doesn't actually have to be stuck for say. All I need is make it look like it is by **extending its background** all the way to the left

The put such a background I want to use an empty div outside the grid that will looks like [this](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/101MoAVXUIV_sxgapIcbl6aL_024EqyDEF8f0N6JWJdw/edit): verifying theses:

- its **(top,left)** corner is **(0,0)**
- its **height** is same as **sidebar**
- it **width** is the distance **(0,0)** to **(x,y)** where (x,y) is **top-right** corner of the sidebar

NB: (x,y) moves as the windows browser is resized, which make the problem hard for me.

I don't know if I made my problem clear but I hope someone will know what to do. Also please tell me if you think this approach isn't a good option.

Answer (score 0):

If i think what your willing its really easly

just make a div

and this is the css

```
#divname{
    posision:fixed;
    top:25%;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    width:100%;/* make sure the body is 100% to*/
}
```

and the height is just the 100% your using in the sidebar